# Is there any (shadow?) css property for spacing around text on a submit input?

Tags: html, css, firefox

In Firefox extra spacing is added around the text value (not just vertical space as would be the case from line-height, but horizontal as well).

Chrome, Opera (has a slightly different line-height issue), and even IE all render submit buttons without adding any extra space.

http://jsfiddle.net/jswartwood/aFCwj/

If you open firebug and hover over the <a> and <input> respectively, you can see that it is not padding, etc.

From the sound of the [bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=349259#c1) it seems that Firefox puts a "block" inside these form elements?!?! If this is true, why? This makes visual button size very difficult to keep consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through the Firefox source code (*layout/style/forms.css*) I found `::-moz-focus-inner` to be the shadow selector I needed.

I still disagree with mozilla's choice of forcing line-height, but that is another story; in the mean time I may be able to normalize all browsers by setting line-height: normal.

```
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jswartwood/aFCwj/14/

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question:  I do not believe CSS can successfully style the input submit element perfectly consistent across all browsers.

Every browser renders these elements differently.  Explorer's buttons are in keeping with Windows.  Safari's buttons are in keeping with Mac styling.  Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc. are going to do their own thing.

When it's important enough for your design that the submit button look the same across all browsers, you would create a custom graphic and make that your button.

Simply replace your submit button code with the following...

```
<input type="image" src="myButtonImage.jpg" alt="" />
```

You can optionally use CSS Sprites or JavaScript to swap button images on hover, click, etc.

Comment: No thanks, I'm happily converting all buttons from images to text already.  Maintenance on a huge application isn't worth the work and I18n is absurd w/ images.  I'm ok with degraded support in legacy browsers, but modern FF has no excuse.  We need browser manufactures to right these wrongs; if web is meant to be more semantic, CSS solutions must get implemented.

Comment: @Action Jake:  You can hardly slam Firefox or any browser for being wrong here unless they failed to follow a "Standard".  Maybe Firefox gets it correct and the other browsers are out of compliance?  Of course that's all a matter of opinion until the W3C "standardizes" this.

Comment: Understood, not a slam.  I <3 FF.  Was just frustrated with their decision.

Answer (score 0):

A button doesn't have to be a button. You can use any other element, like `a` in your example, or even better `span`. And bind it click event to submit your form.

Comment: I could, but when I want a submit button, I should be able to use a submit button.  I know all sorts of "tricks", and I'm not trying to be a smart-ass, I want to **fix** (not _hack_) the cross-browser annoyances.  That's why I specifically asked for **Shadow** CSS selector/property in my question.